# Is there a way to keep request body structure unchanged in FastAPI (pydantic)?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

During a `POST` request, I would like to keep the request body unchanged as per the definition of the `BaseModel` irrespective of what the user has passed.

Consider the below `BaseModel`:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Address(BaseModel):
    city: Optional[str]
    state: Optional[str]
    pinCode: Optional[str]

class User_ReqModel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    mobile: Optional[str]
    address: Optional[Address]
```

Now if I try to access `User_ReqModel.address.city` for the request body `{"name": "Amit Pathak"}` then it throws an error since the `address` object is not present in the body.

The two ways I can avoid this are by -

1. Performing checks for null values is not feasible as I have a comparatively larger request body and cannot validate all attributes.
2. I used the dict object of the `BaseModel` by accessing `User_ReqModel.dict()` and then using `.get('key', {})` but this does not look clean and want to avoid it.

Is there a way I can get the request body structure as defined by my `BaseModel`? That is, I want the below request format for a body `{"name": "Amit Pathak"}`.

```json
{
    "name": "Amit Pathak",
    "mobile": null,
    "address": {
        "city": null,
        "state": null,
        "pinCode": null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a default, empty object as the default value for `address`:

```py
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class Address(BaseModel):
    city: Optional[str]
    state: Optional[str]
    pinCode: Optional[str]

class User_ReqModel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    mobile: Optional[str]
    address: Optional[Address] = Address()
    
    
@app.post("/foo")
async def get_user(user: User_ReqModel):
    return user
```

This will give you the structure you're looking for:

```py
>>> requests.post('http://localhost:8000/foo', json={'name': 'foo bar'}).json()
{
  'name': 'foo bar', 
  'mobile': None, 
  'address': {
    'city': None, 
    'state': None, 
    'pinCode': None
  }
}
```

If you give a value for the address field, it will be deserialized as you expect:

```py
>>> requests.post('http://localhost:8000/foo', json={'name': 'foo bar', 'address': {'city': 'baz'}}).json()
{
  'name': 'foo bar', 
  'mobile': None, 
  'address': {
    'city': 'baz', 
    'state': None, 
    'pinCode': None
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

simple solution will be using `Field` from pydantic, then you can provide default value.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class Address(BaseModel):
    city: Optional[str] = Field(default= None)
    state: Optional[str]
    pinCode: Optional[str]

class User_ReqModel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    mobile: Optional[str]
    address: Optional[Address]
```

you can read more about this [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-fields/)